# Magento Print an individual Customer Group Price List in phpMyAdmin

Tags: customer, price, group

I have a few different customer groups setup. Please help to write an SQL script that runs directly in phpMyAdmin for a list of "group price" for a customer group (id = 68 in my case). My desired result are columns: `SKU`, `Name`, `Group Price`

I tried 2 codes below which did not produce my desired result. I'm a web designer :)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM catalog_product_entity_group_price 
 WHERE catalog_product_entity_group_price.customer_group_id = '68';
```

and

```
   SELECT catalog_product_entity_group_price.*, catalog_product_entity.sku as sku   
     FROM catalog_product_entity_group_price 
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_group_price.entity_id
 GROUP BY catalog_product_entity_group_price.customer_group_id = 68;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've played around with the script & the code below fits my need. Just in case someone needs it:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    catalog_product_entity_group_price 
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity 
        ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_group_price.entity_id     
WHERE 
    catalog_product_entity_group_price.customer_group_id = '68';
```